# Angular get component reference by exporting using exportAs

Tags: angular, typescript

I've two components child & parent

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="currentHierarchyList " [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: hierarchyList}"></ng-container>
    <ng-template #currentHierarchyList let-hierarchyTmplVar>
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
     //some other code
    </ng-template>

 // other HTML template code


  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  exportAs: 'compareHierarchyList'
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  @ViewChild('hierarchyList', { static: true, read: TemplateRef }) hierarchyList: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

In child component I have created one template which I need to project in parent component and used `exportAs` property to export the component instance

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
   <div>
   <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="child.currentHierarchyList" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ 
   $implicit: child.hierarchyList}"></ng-container>
  <app-child #child="compareHierarchyList"></app-child>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {

}
```

Now in parent component when I use this property `#child="compareHierarchyList"` since I need component Instance, issue is it also displays entire child component in parent `<app-child #child="compareHierarchyList"></app-child>`.

I need to know is there any other way by which I can get component instance in typescript when exported using exportAs property?

Comment: `exportAs` is actually meant to be used for directives: `@Directive({ selector: '[dir]', exportAs: 'dir' }) class DirDirective {}` select the directive, not the component using `<my-component dir #directive="dir" #component></my-component>` - Also if you write `<app-child></app-child>` in the template, then you'll get this inside your component, there's no way around it

Comment: child is of type ChildComponent **without** you use `#child="compareHierarchyList"`. You should can write directly:`child.hierarchyList` in your parent simply adding the template reference variable `#child`

Comment: @Eliseo How come child is of type ChildComponent ? Its just an local variable we're setting to set the parent's instance.u mean to say `<ng-container #child [ngTemplateOutlet]="child.currentHierarchyList" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ 
   $implicit: child.hierarchyList}"></ng-container>`??

Comment: @Urvashi, you wrote: `<app-child #child="compareHierarchyList"></app-child>`. A template reference variable (this `#child`), if is in a html tag is from .html the own tag -using ViewChild is an ElementRef-, but when is in a component the template reference variable is the own component, so we can access to all the public variables and function of the component -in Angular by defect all are public-)